# Selecting element by a content text

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Is there a simple way (I mena only by a selector) to select element that has some specific 'content text'?.

For example, we can have the following situation

```
<div>
 <div class="a">text 1</div>
 <div class="a">text 2</div>
 <div class="a">text 3</div>
</div>
```

we can do something like

```
$('div div.a').each(function() {
    if( ($this).text() == "text 1") {
       // do something
    }
});
```

but is there a way we can do something like:

```
 $('div div.a[text="text 1"])
```

or

```
 $('div div.a').someEMBEDEDfunction('text 1')
```

?

Comment: you have :contains selector but it is not equal to 'equal'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`contains`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

```
$('div div.a:contains("text 1"))
```

Something to take into account is that this selector is case sensitive. If you need a case insensitive version, you'll need to implement your own selector or override existing one.

Comment: is it a CSS feature or jQuery ?

Comment: was CSS but still used by sizzle (jquery) but it is not equal to 'equal' ;)

Comment: @OskarSzura: it's a jquery selector.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a much more complex answer that involves the `.contents()` method, nodeTypes and innerHTML. I like Claudio's much better!